# Adapt application features according to device performance

Tags: android, performance

I am developing a quite CPU demanding application that only run perfectly in high end devices. I want to support a wide range of Android devices limiting the amount of simultaneous features. The app doesn't do much graphics and all the CPU processing is done using the NDK.

Basically I have a set of 15 parallel processes (sound and image) that work smooth in high end devices. In low end I discovered that 5 processes work pretty decent although the app is not feature completed.

Each process runs and algorithm that process lots sequential data, so it doesn't finish until completing all the set.

Do you have any suggestion how can I limit the features according to the device?

Comment: Usually, for CPU intensive tasks, people use the NDK.

Comment: can we get some more info--are you using a main loop?  Or can you give us a brief rundown of the architecture you have implemented?

Comment: I already added a bit more info